# Samsung Note 1 is Loading Resources From Xhdpi Folder

Tags: android, resolution, samsung-mobile, android-drawable

I am having this issue where I have HDPI and XHDPI folders in my eclipse project both have different images resolutions, both Images in the different folders are exactly the same but they differ in size.

So I lunched my app on Samsung Galaxy Note 1 which have `800 x 1280 pixels, 5.3 inches (~285 ppi pixel density)` display, but it's loading drawables from the XHDPI folder.

I have tested that by modifying one image in HDPI folder and keep it as it is in the XHDPI folder, the result was note 1 is loading from the XHDPI folder, am I missing something here, it suppose to load images from the HDPI folder because it's screen density is smaller than 320 DPI.

Comment: Have you made sure by cleaning the project after you modified the image? There might be the possibility that the build process did not recognized the changed picture.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: yes I am positive I have cleaned before testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what density your device is set to with

```
Log.v(TAG, "density=" + getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
```

Answer (score 1):

> am I missing something here, it suppose to load images from the HDPI folder because it's screen density is smaller than 320 DPI

The maker of the device chooses which density bucket to use. Since ~285 is closer to 320 than 240, it is not surprising to me that Samsung chose `-xhdpi`. [Others have reported that it indeed is an `-xhdpi` device](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/).

If you are finding that `-xhdpi` resources result in slightly too large of images in certain places, you may need to control that in those places (e.g., set the `ImageView` size to the size that you want and set `android:scaleType` to be how you want the image to be adjusted).

Answer (score 0):

On Android developer website, it says,

"hdpi   Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
xhdpi   Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi)."

Any device which has a density **higher than 240dpi** should load layouts and images from xhdpi folder.

Thus, your app on galaxy note which has 285dpi loads images from xhdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

> it suppose to load images from the HDPI folder because it's screen density is smaller than 320 DPI.

why that?

**HDPI** is **240** ppi

**XHDPI** is **320** ppi

Note 1 has a 285 which is closer to **XHDPI** (|285-320|=35) than to **HDPI** (|285-240|=45)